# making Jbutton visible via another Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have two buttons in my Jframe: button1 and button2. Both buttons have their respective codes to execute when they got clicked. However button2 should only be visible when a certain condition in button1 is satisfied. Need help.
How should I do this?

Comment: `JButton#setVisible`?

Comment: Did you even try to read the java doc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html

Comment: *"However button2 should only be visible when a certain condition in button1 is satisfied."*  Probably better to set it (or its `Action`) to be *disabled* until needed.

Comment: did you even google this?!

Comment: Yes and yes I googled it. But I couldn't find any solution to my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially put

```
button2.setVisible(false);
```

In the click event of button1 when condition is satisfied set

```
button2.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Action Event to use visiblity of buttons

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Add Button Action Handler here
        button1.setVisible(false);
        button2.setVisible(true);
    }
}

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Add Button Action Handler here
        button2.setVisible(false);
        button1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```